# Enabling virtualization on a PC

Tags: ios, virtual-machines

I was designing games in unity with some friends but none of us have a mac so none of us can download the apple sdk.  To use the sdk, we will have to run a virtual machine with osx on it.  Virtualization is disabled on most PCs by default and I was wondering if there was any way to change that without rebooting into the bios.  If not, how would I change it in the bios?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/287697/enabling-virtualization-on-a-pc

Comment: Since Unity runs in Windows, I'm not even sure why you'd even need to do this.

Comment: @Tim you can't build the iOS version without OSX.

Comment: I was looking into it and there's something called boot-132 that I could use.  Unlike a hackintosh, it doesn't violate the DMCA and the only part of apple's EULA that it violates is the "you can't install this on a non apple labeled computer," but that's easy.  Put an apple sticker on your computer case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run "legally" OSX on a virtual machine. In fact, Apple grant licenses for their stuff only, so you can't run OSX on a non Apple computer, even if it is virtually.

But there is some way to do it using **Virtual Box** or **VMWare** and a slightly modified version of osx...

- Virtual Box: http://www.virtualbox.org/
- VMWare: http://www.vmware.com/

For more informations, see this StackOverflow link, "**Is it possible to run OSX in a virtual machine?**": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159/is-it-possible-to-run-osx-in-a-virtual-machine

Comment: I was thinking of that, but will I be able to run the apple sdk on vmware or virtual box?

Comment: I'm currently running OS-X Snow Leopard on Virtual Box 4 (under Linux) and all is fine. I can use the apple SDKs, Xcode etc. or even run World of Goo. The only problem is that Virtual Box is limited to OpenGL 1.5 as far as I know... (there is no official support for OS-X). So you can compile, but you will probably be unable to run 3D applications (I send compiled app using 3D on a real Mac to test them)... except this problem that's ok.